Verify SSH commit is signed (not verifying the validity of the signature)
Is there a quick command to check if I signed a specific commit?
(notice I'm not asking how to verify a signature. I just want to know: is the commit signed? yes or no)
I tried the following, but all of them tell me the commit is NOT signed:
 git log --show-signature HEAD -1
 git verify-commit HEAD
 git log --pretty="format:%h (%aN) %G? %GG %GK %GF" HEAD -1

All of the above show something for GPG signatures, but tell me "No signature" if the commit was signed with an SSH key.
The only command that tells the whole truth is cat-file commit:
$ git cat-file commit HEAD
tree 896fba0491baa9f122a2eae5bcd8b052c6481272
parent 97031bccd6744e24028be294059e5a24a454cb58
author [...]
committer [...]
gpgsig -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----
[...]
 -----END SSH SIGNATURE-----

[...]

My signed commits get marked as Verified on GitHub, as expected.
I am guessing SSH signature checks are not as well supported by as GPG signature checks. I can even imagine why more security-conscious maintainers of git may dislike SSH signing support.
But my original, practical question remains. Is there a more convenient way than cat-file to verify I signed a commit?

If you only need to verify the signature of some users (eg, double check if your commit is signed before pushing it to GitHub). These are the steps.
When I run git verify-commit HEAD the error message gives a hint of the necessary actions:
error: gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile needs to be configured and exist for ssh signature verification

It seems git ignores a signature it cannot verify, ie, it does not report an existing signature that could not be verified.
In order to allow git to recognize the SSH signature, you need to tell if that SSH key is valid for a given user.
For that need to create a file in the format of "ALLOWED SIGNERS" from man ssh-keygen.
For example, create a file ~/.config/git/allowed_signers with content:
user@example.com ssh-ed25519 AAAB4..

Then configure git to use it for SSH signature verification:
git config --global gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile ~/.config/git/allowed_signers

Now, git log --show-header would show that a commit is signed:
$ git log --show-signature -1
commit 9c4cbb031d1d6c49dee19713747a828702a8e42a
Good "git" signature for user@exaple.com with ED25519 key ...
Author: User <user@example.com>
Date:   ...

Also, git would report if a commit has a valid SSH signature.
$ git verify-commit HEAD
Good "git" signature for user@example.com with ED25519 key ...

Or course, you would need to add each trusted user and its key.
Source: https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2021/11/16/git-ssh-signatures/

Thank you for this, but my question explicitly says: I am not trying to verify a signature. Furthermore my question is about SSH signatures not GPG.

Upon re-reading I think this is a great answer, but I can't update my vote just yet.

I see, maybe I wasn't clear that this works with git log, so I've added an example of it.

memoselyk, the updated answer references a --show-header option which I don't think exists (unless my git is outdated) the snippet below it uses --show-signature which works.

You are on the right track.

git show will show you if the commit is signed or not

Here is a demo which i assume is similar to what you did, and you will see that the commit is signed


#!/bin/bash

# Prepare repo
cd        /tmp
rm -rf    /tmp/local-repo
git init  /tmp/local-repo

# Switch to the new repo
cd /tmp/local-repo

# Set up local repository flags fo sign
git config user.name   "user"
git config user.email  "email"
git config gpg.format  ssh
git config user.signingkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# Add some dummy content
echo a > a.txt 

# Commit the changes
git add .
git commit -s -m "Initial commit"

echo -e ""
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git verify-commit HEAD"
git verify-commit HEAD

echo -e ""
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git show HEAD"
git show HEAD

Output
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/local-repo/.git/
[main (root-commit) 623ab49] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------

$ git verify-commit HEAD

----------------------------------------------------------------

$ git show HEAD
commit 623ab49b6fe911960494006ee0b80a7cd982b6a2 (HEAD -> main)
Author: user <email>
Date:   Sat Apr 27 01:21:12 2024 +0300

    Initial commit
    
    Signed-off-by: user <email>

diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..7898192
--- /dev/null
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+a


git commit -s doesn't sign the commit, git commit -S does.

On my mac -s also works :-) since i added the key as config value

git verify-commit HEAD prints nothing so the commit is not signed. git show HEAD doesn't show anything about a cryptographic signature so the commit is not signed. I don't know why do you thing it's signed. Do you confuse cryptographic signature with signed-off trailer?

Sorry, but this (great) answer is about -s which adds a line to the commit message. My question is about -S which cryptographically signs the commit.

Git's checking signature validity, if you want to check a much more primitive requirement, the presence of something that appears to be a signature, without verifying that is actually is one, it's only a question of when you stop looking.
Simplest that passes my personal sniff test, on GNU/anything:
didisign() {
if sed -n '0,/^$/ { /^gpgsig -----BEGIN /,/^ -----END / {//q}; };$q1' <<EOD
$(git cat-file commit ${1-HEAD})
EOD
then echo ${1-HEAD} appears to have been signed
else echo ${1-HEAD} has not been signed
fi
}

and Git's generating and checking the commit headers anyway, so there's no particular reason to get too specific about what kind of signature it is, Git said gpgsig and what follows looks conventional enough. Anybody putting any real effort into forging a signature, your only recourse is to check its validity the real way anyway, anything between a glance and full validity checking is a half-measure.
edit: not to put too fine a point on it,

Is there a more convenient way than cat-file to verify I signed a commit?

well, no, this could easily be misleading in general use, nothing wrong with the quick check but you're going to have to look at the commit.

Thank you for your answer, but my question is explicitly asking for a method other than cat-file, furthermore my question is about SSH signature, and your answer is about GPG signatures, although it could be easily adapted.

The marker for all signatures is gpgsig, SSH signatures, introduced well over ten years after Git was written, are identified by their wrapper lines, -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE and such. I tested the answer on an SSH-signed commit. Your other point I addressed explicitly in the answer.

If a commit's signature doesn't verify, the commit is not signed. Git won't tell you a commit is signed when it isn't. You might as well be asking how to turn on the lights on a car without using the light switch: you look at raw commit data with git cat-file commit or some equivalent, if you just want to know whether it might have been signed, you look at the raw commit data.

Thank you for the clarification, you did answer my question now (by saying 'no').
What I was hoping for is some more human-friendly flag, e.g. git show --show-signature but it seems no such thing exists.
